# Error while using sqrt in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, calculator

I'm coding a calculator for my stats class but I'm having issues with my code. This is for calculating Confidence Intervals. I'm getting the "error more than one instance of overloaded function" when I use `sqrt`. Also have a couple of other problems which I cannot identify. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and using the win32 console application. If you could help me it'll help a lot. (I'm new to coding so bear with my awful coding.)

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #pragma warning(disable: 4996)

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
   double sample = 0, z = 0, sample1 = 0;
   double std = 0, error = 0, sampleroot = 0, error1 = 0;

   printf("What is the Z score?");
   scanf("%d\n", &z);

printf("What is the std?");
scanf("%lf\n", &std);

printf("What is the sample size?");
scanf("%d\n", &sample);

printf("What is the Error?");
scanf("%lf", &error);

//sampleroot = sqrt(sample);
error1 = z * (std/sqrt((double)sample));
sample1 = ((z * std) / error) * ((z * std) / error);

printf("Error = %lf\n", error1);
printf("Sample is %d\n", sample1);


system("pause");
return 0;
  }
```

That my new code. When i run it, it only asks the first 3 printfs and skips directly to the solution. How do I fix this.

Comment: Note that `<cstdlib>` is a pure C++ header and cannot be used sanely in C programs.  Overloading is also a problem in C++ and not in C; there are no overloaded functions in C.  Hence, you're not working in C — you're using your C++ compiler in a C++ mode, not in a C mode, if you get it anywhere near compiling.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &z);` remove `\n` --> `scanf("%d", &z);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three sqrt functions in C++:

```
double sqrt(double _X);
float sqrt(float _X);
long double sqrt(long double _X);
```

You have `sample` declared as an int (which can convert to float or double), so the compiler doesn't know which function to call.

You could pick the one you want and typecast, `sqrt((double)sample)`, or you probably just want to declare sample as double to begin with. In fact, you probably want all your `int`s to be `double`s.

**edit**
You need a `&` before `error` in `scanf("%lf", &error);` Also I think you'll want to remove all the `\n` from your `scanf()` formats.

Comment: i inserted sqrt((double)sample) but still get Unhandled exception at 0x0f9700d8 (msvcr100d.dll) in Stats.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: You need a `&` in this statement `scanf("%lf", &error);`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me. Here is the working code if anyone wants to use it for finding error and sample size in Confidence Intervals.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
double sample = 0, z = 0, sample1 = 0;
double std = 0, error = 0, sampleroot = 0, error1 = 0;

printf("What is the Z score?");
scanf("%lf", &z);

printf("What is the std?");
scanf("%lf", &std);

printf("What is the sample size?");
scanf("%lf", &sample);

printf("What is the Error?");
scanf("%lf", &error);

//sampleroot = sqrt(sample);
error1 = z * (std/sqrt((double)sample));
sample1 = ((z * std) / error) * ((z * std) / error);

printf("Error = %lf\n", error1);
printf("Sample is %d\n", sample1);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```